.Net ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory not extracting macOS file alias from zip
I have a folder containing a file and an alias to that file that I've compressed into a Zip. However, when I try to extract it using the .Net ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory API, the alias is not extracted properly. Opening it causes macOS to treat it like a generic document, and not an alias to the file. Is the some flag that I'm just not setting right?


My code is as follows:
var zipPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"./sample files.zip");
var extractPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"./sample files - extract");
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);


What is the purpose of an alias directly besides the actual file? I would assume the alias points to a path where the file was when creating the zip. So it would not work when extracting into a different path.

The Zip file contains an App, which has aliases in the Frameworks directory. In this case, using a dmg  isn't an option.

I ultimately decided it would be easiest to just call ditto as a subprocess, since it will extract the aliases properly
var dittoProcess = new Process();
var args = $"-k -x \"{archivePath}\" \"{outDirectory}\"";
dittoProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/ditto", args);
dittoProcess.Start();
dittoProcess.WaitForExit();


You can try posting the issue to the .net runtime project on github. The fact that the built-in tools handle this case correctly is a good reason to suspect a bug in the .net implementation. Or at least they can list the limitations in the docs.
